# Track input element changes outside my angular component

Tags: angular

I am working with angular web components. Now here i have my angular web component integrated to a normal html page. How can i track the changes in the input values of input elements which is outside my angular component.

```
<html>

<body>
<div>
   <input type="text" id="inputID">
<div>
<div>
   <angular-component></angular-component>
<div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to listen to the input type text value changes in my angular component

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little confusing, but i think you could track your input values through a service.

You could capture the value of your inputs inside service variables and make it accessible in the whole app.